# Proof verification: For isomorphism $\phi : G\to H$, prove that $G$ has subgroup of order $n$ iff $H$ has subgroup of order $n$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Could someone please verify my following proof?

> For isomorphism $\phi : G\to H$ of the groups $G$ and $H$, prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$ iff $H$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

**Proof:** Let $K\leq G$ with $|K|=n$. Then $\phi (K)$ is the image of $K$ under $\phi$. By the definition of $\phi$, $\phi(K) \subset H$. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism that maps a group to a group, $\phi(K)$ is a group. Then $\phi(K) \leq H$. Since $\phi$ is bijective and $\phi(K)=K$ (?), $|\phi(K)|=|K|=n$. Then $H$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

> I don't know a good way to express $\phi(K)=K$ because I think $\phi(K)=K$ is incorrect.

Let $I\leq H$ with $|I|=n$. Then $\phi (I)$ is the image of $I$ under $\phi$. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, the inverse $\phi ^{-1}: H \to G$ exists. Then by the definition of $\phi ^{-1}$,  $\phi ^{-1}(I) \subset G$. Since $\phi ^{-1}$ is an isomorphism that maps a group to a group, $\phi ^{-1}(I)$ is a group. Then $\phi^{-1}(I) \leq G$. Since $\phi^{-1}$ is bijective and $\phi^{-1}(I)=I$ (?), $|\phi^{-1}(I)|=|I|=n$. Then $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

Comment: Technically, $\phi(I) = I$ means that the image of $\phi$ is the same set as $I$. You should express it differently.

Comment: @user357980 Is it possible that I don't need to express this at all for the proof to be valid? And what do you think of this proof overall? Do you think it is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me copy-past the first half of your proof.

**Proof:** Let $K\leq G$ with $|K|=n$. Then $\phi (K)$ is the image of $K$ under $\phi$. By the definition of $\phi$, $\phi(K) \subset H$. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism that maps a group to a group, $\phi(K)$ is a group.

> I wouldn't say "since $\phi$ is an isomorphism that maps a group to a group", the good reason for $\phi(K)$ to be a group is simply "since $\phi$ is a group morphism" and then you may continue with "it sends groups to groups", and end up with "thus $\phi(K)$ is a group". In your formulation, it is not clear whether you use the "iso" part or the "morphism" part in isomorphism. Furthermore, it sounds like "mapping a group to a group" is something that may or may not be verified an isomorphism but happens to be verified for $\phi$ whereas it is always true.

Then $\phi(K) \leq H$. Since $\phi$ is bijective and $\phi(K)=K$ (?), $|\phi(K)|=|K|=n$.

> As you probably guessed it given the question mark $\phi(K)=K$ has absolutely no reason at all to be true or to even make sense given that they are not subset of the same sets a priori. I would write instead "Since $\phi$ is bijective, $|\phi(K)|=|K|=n$." Remark that the very definition of cardinality imposes that the cardinality of $K$ and $\phi(K)$ have to be the same.

Then $H$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

> I would rather write, "Thus $\phi(K)$ is a subgroup of $H$ of order $n$".

Let $I\leq H$[...]

> You seem to have copy-pasted the first part of the answer and switch $G$ and $H$, $\phi$ to $\phi^{-1}$ and $K$ to $I$. This a good idea. Why don't you just write that one can apply what you have just proved to $\phi^{-1}:H\to G$? This is a completely legitimate thing to write at this point (i.e. when you have done the first part correctly) and much more time efficient.

Comment: Thank you for going through my proof and giving me helpful advice on proof-writing!